# Why does printing inner class prints as if it's a module's variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I print the inner class in Python why does it get printed as if it's a module variable (`__main__.FInner`) rather than getting printed as `__main__.F.FInner` or something nested?

```
class F(object):

    class FInner:
        x = 1


x = F()
print x.FInner  # __main__.FInner
```

or even if I use the newer style inner class style the output remains similar

```
class F(object):

    class FInner(object):
        x = 1


x = F()
print x.FInner  #  <class '__main__.FInner'>
```

Comment: Why are you nesting classes? And why is the inner class an old-style class?

Comment: I am using https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . It recommends to add an inner class named Meta in an old style fasion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) method for classes in Python (or for `object` maybe?) simply displays `module.ClassName` by default. Because of this, a class `Foo` will be displayed as `module.Foo` regardless of how nested it is within e.g., other classes, because it is still in `module`.

If you execute your script directly, `module` will be `__main__`, but if you import your class in another module, it will show up as `my_module.ClassName` instead - again, regardless of how nested it is.

The documentation for `__repr__()` (linked above) says of the string returned by this method:

> it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous

In a situation like the following:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     class Bar(object):
...             class Baz(object):
...                     pass
... 
>>> Foo.Bar.Baz
<class '__main__.Baz'>
```

`<class '__main__.Baz'>` is certainly not very "information-rich", nor is it unambiguous, since a top-level class named `Baz` would have the exact same `__repr__()` string. However, nested classes in Python are very rare, in my experience as least. Even in the case of a nested class, it is likely that any important information will come from the attributes of the class, or the classes it inherits from, rather than the namespace it happens to occupy. I can certainly understand your curiosity though.